# Why is my Scrapy spider duplicating it's output?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm attempting to scrape a website to get a very rough demographic of it's users (no personally identifying information or photos), but the tutorial spider from the official documentation I've modified is repeating the same line of output 4 times in a row.

A copy of the code I'm using is below:

**Note** that the example profile I've included in the code is a fake/spam account. In the case where it may have already been deleted, you can replace the url with any other on the site and it will work again.

```
import scrapy

class DateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "date"
start_urls = [
    'http://www.pof.com/viewprofile.aspx?profile_id=141659067',
]

def parse(self, response):
    for container in response.xpath('//div[@class="user-details-wide"]'):
        yield {
            'Gender': response.xpath("//span[@id='gender']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Age': response.xpath("//span[@id='age']/text()").extract_first(),
            'State': response.xpath("//span[@id='state_id']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Marital status': response.xpath("//span[@id='maritalstatus']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Body': response.xpath("//span[@id='body']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Height': response.xpath("//span[@id='height']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Ethnicity': response.xpath("//span[@id='ethnicity']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Does drugs?': response.xpath("//span[@id='drugs']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Smokes?': response.xpath("//span[@id='smoke']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Drinks?': response.xpath("//span[@id='drink']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Has children?': response.xpath("//span[@id='haschildren']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Wants children?': response.xpath("//span[@id='wantchildren']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Star sign': response.xpath("//span[@id='zodiac']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Education': response.xpath("//span[@id='college_id']/text()").extract_first(),
            'Personality': response.xpath("//span[@id='fishtype']/text()").extract_first(),
        }
```

Running as follows:

```
scrapy crawl date -o date.scv
```

The output I'm looking for is *one* row of headers followed by *one* line of results straight after it, not the whitespace and duplicates I'm currently getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use for loop. Simply find a span element and extract all data from him.

Also, I suggest you use scrapy items it's more convenient.
One way to clean extracted data from whitespace is to use xpath function [normalize-space()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space).

```
import scrapy
from items import DateSpiderItem


class DateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "date"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.pof.com/viewprofile.aspx?profile_id=141659067',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = DateSpiderItem()
        item['Gender'] = response.xpath(
            "//span[@id='gender']/text()").extract_first()
        item['Age'] = response.xpath(
            "//span[@id='age']/text()").extract_first()
        item['State'] = response.xpath(
            "//span[@id='state_id']/text()").extract_first()
        item['Marital_status'] = response.xpath(
            "normalize-space(//span[@id='maritalstatus']/text())").extract_first()
        item['Body'] = response.xpath(
            "//span[@id='body']/text()").extract_first()
        item['Height'] = response.xpath(
            "//span[@id='height']/text()").extract_first()
        item['Ethnicity'] = response.xpath(
            "//span[@id='ethnicity']/text()").extract_first()
        item['Does_drugs'] = response.xpath(
            "normalize-space(//span[@id='drugs']/text())").extract_first()
        item['Smokes'] = response.xpath(
            "//span[@id='smoke']/text()").extract_first()
        item['Drinks'] = response.xpath(
            "normalize-space(//span[@id='drink']/text())").extract_first()
        item['Has_children'] = response.xpath(
            "normalize-space(//span[@id='haschildren']/text())").extract_first()
        item['Wants_children'] = response.xpath(
            "normalize-space(//span[@id='wantchildren']/text())").extract_first()
        item['Star_sign'] = response.xpath(
            "//span[@id='zodiac']/text()").extract_first()
        yield item
```

Items file:

```
class DateSpiderItem(scrapy.Item):
    Gender = scrapy.Field()
    Age = scrapy.Field()
    State = scrapy.Field()
    Marital_status = scrapy.Field()
    Body = scrapy.Field()
    Height = scrapy.Field()
    Ethnicity = scrapy.Field()
    Does_drugs = scrapy.Field()
    Smokes = scrapy.Field()
    Drinks = scrapy.Field()
    Has_children = scrapy.Field()
    Wants_children = scrapy.Field()
    Star_sign = scrapy.Field()
    Education = scrapy.Field()
    Personality = scrapy.Field()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Had to move and rename a few files, but I got your code to work. And it looks so much neater as well! Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help you.